# Trying to tcpdump and capture GET requests that end with a string

Tags: tcpdump

So I have the basic capture for GET

tcpdump blah blah blah -w /var/tmp/filename 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'

But this just captures ALL 'GET ' requests coming thru the box which is the equivalent of drinking water from niagara falls.

I specifically have to narrow down my search to these GET requests that contain "c=AAAAAAAA"

The whole URI looks like this:  GET /ClientDesktop.Main?c=AAAAAAAA

The capture i built (which doesnt work betcause of the :4 in the filter i suppose) looks like this:

tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x474554202f436c69656e744465736b746f702e4d61696e3f633d4141414141414141

I'd love to just look for the AAAAAAAA but the :4 I think forces me to start at the GET / therefore the need for the whole bunch of 0xchars ending in my desired AAAAAAAA.

Does anyone know what Im missing?  I cannot grep for this (i believe) becuase I am capturing to a file with the -w function.

Any help is great.   Thanks folks.